# Not able to use pd.panel to Convert dictionary data to panel

Tags: pandas, dictionary, panel

created a dictionary that stores two columns of the dataframe.All necessary libraries are imported.

Below is the code :

```
d = { 'ClassA' : df['Student_height'] , 'ClassB' :df['Student_weight']}

p = pd.Panel(d)
```

Here I am getting error 
There is no problem with my dict as well 
I dunno what is the error here?

Comment: can you put the stacktrace here, that would be more helpful

Comment: Actually the error msg was tuple error .

Comment: Later I used a different approach where I converted the dataframe to two dict and passed it to the panel. But my question was why can't I pass the entire dataframe directly as input to dictionary and convert that dict to panel?

Comment: converting the dataframe columns to dict and then using it is the best way.